# jdbc PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CONFLICT"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to update a table in my postgres DB with JDBC, and for most of my queries it works just fine. But sometime I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CONFLICT"
```

When I do the request manually in postgres it works just fine:

```
INSERT INTO user_jira (key_user,account_id,name_user,email_adress,display_name,active)
VALUES ('admin','5a283eThisIsJustAnExample','admin','john.john@proceedit.com','john john',true)
ON CONFLICT (key_user) 
DO UPDATE 
  SET account_id=excluded.account_id,
      name_user=excluded.name_user,
      email_adress=excluded.email_adress,
      display_name=excluded.display_name,
      active=excluded.active;
```

Does anyone konws whats going on?
Edit: here is how I connect to the db and send my query:

```
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db";//connect(url);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user","user");
    props.setProperty("password","*********");
    try {
        dyDATAconn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        System.out.println("connected to "+url);
        Statement st;
         //sql statement
        st = dyDATAconn.createStatement();
        int userRowInserted = st.executeUpdate(User.sqlUpdate(newUser));
        int taskRowInserted = st.executeUpdate(Task.sqlUpdate(allTask));
        int timeSpentRowInserted = st.executeUpdate(TimeSpent.sqlUpdate(allTimeSpent));
        System.out.println("tsk: "+taskRowInserted+"\nTS:"+timeSpentRowInserted);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("connection to dyJIRA@dyDATA failed");
        System.out.println(User.sqlUpdate(newUser));
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```

I can't show how I create my query, but I only got pb with users and the requests are all the same format as the one above

Comment: What is the exact version of the Postgres JDBC driver you are using? Are you maybe using batching with your JDBC code together with `reWriteBatchedInserts=true`?

Comment: Please show the actual code used

Comment: I'm using postgres JDBC 4.2 (I think), the driver is  version 42.2.5

Comment: And how does that code generate the query? BTW: Your use of `Statement` and `executeUpdate(String)` suggests your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: The query is made by reading an JSON file containing all the data, injecting this data in a list of User objects (with fields that match the DB table), and making a sql query string out of all the fields with User.sqlUpdate(List<User> allUser).